# Angular/ mat-error не работает

Tags: angular

Ребята всем привет, создал кастомный валидатор в Angular7.\<\mat error/>- не работает с ngIf, хотя все условия соблюдены были.С другими тегами все работает, подскажите что не так?

```
export function passwordEqual(form: AbstractControl){
  const areEqual = form.value.password === form.value.repeatPassword;
  return !areEqual ? { notEqual: true} : null;
}
```

Ниже template

```
<form
  [formGroup]="signUpForm"
  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
>
  <mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Repeat Password"
      formControlName="repeatPassword"
    >
    <mat-error *ngIf="signUpForm.hasError('notEqual')">
      Password not equal
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

И ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup({
      repeatPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    },  {validators: passwordEqual, updateOn : 'submit' });    
  }
```

Comment: `mat-error is shown only when a FormControl is invalid`

Comment: Единственное, что я тут придумал, это вынести mat error на уровне формы и тогда- форма будет инвалид и поле сработает...